# dynamically resize div element with "position: absolute" children

Tags: javascript, html, resize, positioning

i'm having the following piece of code:

```
<head>
    <style>
        #mainDiv {
            background-color: grey;
            position: absolute;
        }
        #one {
            height: 150px;
            width: 70px;
            bottom: 300px;
            right: 500px;
            background-color: green;
            position: absolute; 
        }
        #two {
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            margin-top: 50px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            margin-left: 90px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            background-color: blue;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainDiv">
        <div id="one"></div>
        <div id="two"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

i want to resize **#mainDiv** so it will include its children and will consider all positioning and margin attributes (basically #mainDiv's grey area will surround children and visually show the positioning and margins spaces).

i know it can't be done dynamically using CSS. how can i implement such using pure JavaScript **without** the use of JQuery?

note: there's no restriction on children's position attribute it can be any of them but "fixed".

code need to support all major browsers + IE8 + mobile (android 2.3 + 4, iphone).

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use position relative for second div so the mainDiv greay area will surround your children element

```
#mainDiv {
        background-color: grey;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #one {
        height: 150px;
        width: 100px;
        bottom: 300px;
        right: 500px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    #two {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-left: 90px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        background-color: blue;
        position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: thanks @Dinesh unfortunately it's not possible for me due to some restrictions

Answer (score 0):

In your case it's not possible because of some logical reasons.
How is it possible to find a right position for id one when the
parent has no size and therefor no usable right position.

If you are using left instead of right for id one the situation 
becomes better.

all the best

try this one

```
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var elems, max_top, max_right;
        elems = mainDiv.getElementsByTagName( 'div' );
        for( i = 0; i < elems.length; i++ ) {
            elem = elems[ i ].offsetLeft + elems[ i ].offsetWidth + elems[ i ].style.marginLeft;
            max_right = ( max_right > elem ) ? max_right : elem;

            elem = elems[ i ].offsetTop + elems[ i ].offsetHeight + elems[ i ].style.marginBottom;
            max_top = ( max_top > elem ) ? max_top : elem;
        }
        console.log( 't: ' + max_top + ', r: ' + max_right );
        mainDiv.style.height = max_top;
        mainDiv.style.width = max_right;

    }
    </script>
```

The code is having some problem with getting the margins.

I found a good page which solves the problem.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html

Comment: well, element.offsetLeft will return a negative value in this case. the problem is that i can't find a consistent code to recalculate div's size

Comment: @ranweiz i know. but when you change the right into left it becomes much easier finding the highest left's and top's to reset later the parent element

Comment: i agree, and i did write a code that does it. the problem is with the right and bottom as you mentioned and that's why i'm kinda stuck right now

Comment: yup, will def check the site out

Answer (score 0):

I did something maybe complicated that you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/YMmHz/1/

Basically I get all possible values:

```
var widthOne, widthTwo, heightOne, heightTwo;
var leftOne, leftTwo, rightOne, rightTwo, topOne, topTwo, botOne, botTwo;
var marginLeftOne, marginLeftTwo, marginRightOne, marginRightTwo, marginTopOne, marginTopTwo, marginBotOne, marginBotTwo;
var paddingLeftOne, paddingLeftTwo, paddingRightOne, paddingRightTwo, paddingTopOne, paddingTopTwo, paddingBotOne, paddingBotTwo;
var maxWidthOne, maxWidthTwo, maxHeightOne, maxHeightTwo;
```

With different tests:

```
widthOne = $('#one').width();
widthTwo = $('#two').width();

(parseInt($('#one').css('left')))? leftOne = parseInt($('#one').css('left')):leftOne = 0;
(parseInt($('#two').css('left')))? leftTwo = parseInt($('#two').css('left')):leftTwo = 0;
```

And then define the size of the **#mainDiv** like this:

```
(maxWidthOne>=maxWidthTwo)? $('#main_div').width(maxWidthOne):$('#main_div').width(maxWidthTwo);
(maxHeightOne>=maxHeightTwo)? $('#main_div').height(maxHeightOne):$('#main_div').height(maxHeightTwo);
```

Comment: thanks, but although hardcoded values will work great on position absolute and float, it wouldn't work so good on relative... still trying to figure out the magic values to work on all

Comment: Yes but in that case couldn't you just check the value of $('#one').css('position') and if it equal to 'relative' you define the width and height as you want?